# Why is my image loading in firebase storage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-storage, loading

I just uploaded an image to firebase storage using nodejs admin sdk

But when I click on the image it's constantly loading like this

The image size is displayed so it's not zero or anything like that.

[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just a quirk with the firbase console. If you expand the location tab on the bottom of that section there is an access token. Clicking on it will copy a link to the image. Just paste that into a new tab and you can see the image.